# Why does Google sheets return #N/A for MATCH but not for INDEX + MATCH

Tags: function, google-sheets

I have a table with several columns, where I'd like to select one row based on the content of several cells. So this is an application of the `MATCH` function on multiple criteria. This uses the tip explained for instance here https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/multiple-column-match-and-seek-output-value/41966.

An example table:

```
    A    B    C
1   foo  10   FOO10
2   foo  20   FOO20
3   bar  10   BAR10
4   bar  20   BAR20
5   bar  10   BAR10
```

So, if I use the formula

```
=index(C:C,match(1,(A:A="bar")*(B:B=20),0))
```

It works flawless, and I get `BAR20` as expected.

However if I **only want to get the index**, I thought I could do this by simply removing the `index()` function. However when I do this, I get `#N/A` from Google Sheets.

The formula

```
=match(1,(A:A="bar")*(B:B=20),0)
```

returns `#N/A`, with error msg `Did not find value '1' in MATCH evaluation`.

Why is that? How come it works in the `index()` function, but not as standalone? I would expect that if a parameter returns `#N/A`, the function would also return `#N/A`.

Also, as side question, how can we fix that?

Strangely the same example works in Libre Office Calc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work it's because `(A:A="bar")*(B:B=20)` is an array formula, which means that in order to work properly it has to be wrapped in a function that enables arrays.

If you do the following you'll see that the formula returns the expected result:

```
=ArrayFormula(match(1,(A:A="bar")*(B:B=20),0))
```

Some of the functions that enable arrays are:

- ARRAYFORMULA (This function is designed exactly for this)
- INDEX (This is the reason `INDEX(your_formula)` worked)
- SORT
- SORTN
- FILTER
- SUMPRODUCT